# segmentation fault on running UWSim

Tags: ros, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

UWSim; using osgOcean 1.0.1
Building scene...
. Loading cubemaps: 0.340616s
. Generating ocean surface: 0.000218s
. Creating ocean scene: 0.000686s
. Setting up lighting: 1.3e-05s
. Setting localized world: 0.0001s
Complete. Time Taken: 0.34181s
Loading URDF robot...
· GIRONA500/g500_March11.osg: 4.52215s
· ARM5E/ARM5E_part0.osg: 0.128019s
· ARM5E/ARM5E_part1.osg: 0.124858s
· ARM5E/ARM5E_part2.osg: 0.208291s
· ARM5E/ARM5E_part3.osg: 0.754475s
· ARM5E/ARM5E_part4_base.osg: 0.669661s
· ARM5E/ARM5E_part4_jaw1.osg: 0.10166s
· ARM5E/ARM5E_part4_jaw2.osg: 0.097404s
· Linking links...Robot successfully loaded. Total time: 0.017174s
6.62416s
Segmentation fault

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31871/segmentation-fault-on-running-uwsim/) by [michaelowenliu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2183/michaelowenliu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-04-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just run

rosrun UWSim UWSim --disableShaders

Currently, full support for shaders is possible on ATI and NVidia cards. It's possible that your integrated card doesn't support all the shaders required for UWSim. Then you have to run without shaders support, which means you will not see many of the visualization effects like silt, god rays, etc. However, all the functionality should be still there.

Please let me know if that works for you

---

Originally posted by [Mario Prats](https://answers.ros.org/users/1616/mario-prats/) with karma: 291 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michaelowenliu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2183/michaelowenliu/) on 2012-04-20**:
It does work! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, what graphics card do you have?
Could you please try with the --disableShaders option?

---

Originally posted by [Mario Prats](https://answers.ros.org/users/1616/mario-prats/) with karma: 291 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-04-16**:
FYI: I didn't actually ask the question, just added a tag to it :-). @michaelowenliu actually asked the question.

**Comment by [michaelowenliu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2183/michaelowenliu/) on 2012-04-16**:
Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)

**Comment by [michaelowenliu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2183/michaelowenliu/) on 2012-04-16**:
What is the disableShaders option, and how to do with it